# Why doesn't this change el to msgTwo on a second Click of the button?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Shouldn't adding else change the content back to Welcome to our site defined in the msgTwo variable or am I doing this wrong?

```js
let el = document.getElementById('message');
let butt = document.getElementById('clicktodo')
let msg = 'Sign up to our Newsletter for 10% off!';
let msgTwo = 'Welcome to Our Site!';

function change() {
if (el != msg) {
      el.textContent = msg;
  } else {
      el.textContent = msgTwo;
      }
};


butt.addEventListener('click', change);
```

```html
<body>
<h1>
  Traval Worthy
</h1>
<div id="message">
  Welcome to Our Site!
</div>
<button id="clicktodo" style ="padding: 10px 15px; margin-top: 15px">
  Click Here
</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Because you are comparing `el` with `msg`. `el` is of type "DOMElement", and `msg` is of type "string". They can never be equal. You are doing `if(orange==banana)`, it can never be true.

Comment: Thanks for sharing you knowledge you're a Saint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `change` function use `el.textContent` to get text of message element while doing check in `if`

```
if (el.textContent != msg) {
  el.textContent = msg;
} else {
   el.textContent = msgTwo;
}
```

You can also replace this if-else with

```
el.textContent = el.textContent === msg ? msgTwo : msg;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation, you're one of the good ones!